# Javascript Namespace called using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I have a defined namespace:  `Cookies` and under it `ShowLabels` and `ShowOptions`

I want to be able to call the namespace on page using a jquery val assuming it will either return `ShowLabels` or `ShowOptions` IE:

```
Cookies.$.trim($(this).val())
```

How can I do this?

Comment: As per my understanding Cookies is your object and you have ShowLabels & ShowOptions as your methods ?

Comment: I don't suppose it matters but in this case they are properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets to access a property by a string name:

```
Cookies[$.trim($(this).val())]
```